# Is there a way to put highlight gmail schemas of bus tickets?

Tags: gmail, schema.org, google-schemas

I'm working with gmail markup schemas and I want to put highlights like with the Flight Reservation but with bus trips. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I think this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/schemas/reference/bus-reservation#boarding_pass_and_ticket) can help you to determine that. Just check this to know all the possible things that you can do or get with the Google Schemas.

Comment: @Jose Pinto the documentation Kendi provided is what you're looking for. However, BusReservation only integrates with Now. It is currently  supported in Gmail/Inbox like FlightReservation.